# Using KVO to observing view.center in swift for ios give back NSPoint?

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

Here is the code

```
view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "center", options: .New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    guard let change = change else {
        return
    }

    print(change)

    guard let newCenter = change["new"] else {
        return
    }

    print(newCenter.dynamicType)
}
```

And the output is :

```
["new": NSPoint: {50, 50.5}, "kind": 1]
NSConcreteValue
```

I don't know why NS class will appear in iOS. How to correctly observe view.center/frame/transform using KVO with swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since KVO is part of the Objective-C runtime, the change dictionary is an `NSDictionary`, not a native Swift dictionary. An `NSDictionary` can only hold Objective-C objects (which is why, in Swift, it becomes a `[String:AnyObject]`, not a `[String:Any]`), and `CGPoint` is not an Objective-C object. So KVO has to wrap the `CGPoint` in an object.

`NSValue` is a generic Objective-C class for wrapping non-objects, and KVO uses it when the observed property's type is not an object type. `NSValue` is a “class cluster”, which means it defines an interface and may have specialized, non-public subclasses that implement the interface. In this case, you're seeing the name of one of those subclasses: `NSConcreteValue`.

You can get the `CGPoint` value from the `NSValue` by asking for its `CGPointValue` property:

```
guard let newCenter = change["new"]?.CGPointValue else {
    return
}
```

The reason you see `NSPoint` when you print the change dictionary is an accident of history. The `NSPoint` type is older than `CGPoint`, but is now an alias for `CGPoint` on OS X (defined in `Foundation/NSGeometry.h`), and doesn't exist at all on iOS. However, the code to print `NSPoint`/`CGPoint` was not changed to use the new name (probably for backward compatibility) and the same code is used on both OS X and iOS.

Comment: Does `CGRectValue` and `CGSizeValue` exits too?

Comment: Yes they do. Check the [NSValue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/CGSizeValue).